# Certifying software as secure

Tags: audit, standards

What security certifications do major banks in the US expect an external software vendor to comply with? The software might form part of their payment processing system.

ISO/IEC 27001 would apply to an organization's ISM practices. Would the adoption of specific [Center for Internet Security](https://benchmarks.cisecurity.org/downloads/) benchmarks give value addition?

What would be your opinion on [O-TTPF](http://www.opengroup.org/news/press/open-group-launches-accreditation-program-strengthen-global-supply-chain-security) which was approved as ISO/IEC 20243:2015? With software products relying on layers of external software components, it's vital for a customer to rely on a trusted chain.

Comment: This is an opinon-based question where the nature of the question is far too broad to be dealt with on Stackexchange. Furthermore, as @LucasKauffman said, "Certification depends on the nature of the software, how it will be used and where it will be used (country, industry, etc...). Without that specific information we can't help you. "

Comment: I agree that it's too broad. I am looking for some guidelines here as I am limited on the information I can disclose. I shall rephrase my question.

Answer (score 2):

Certification depends on the nature of the software, how it will be used and where it will be used (country, industry, etc...). Without that specific information we can't help you. Third party reporting can be done by several institutions and companies.

ISO27001 is an information security management system, CIS is a company providing services and creating testing guidelines. They are completely different. ISO27001 looks at your organization as a whole, CIS looks at your systems.

My opinion of O-TTPF is that it is useful as it can provide some assurance and thus shift of risk if something goes wrong in your software in the external component.

Comment: Thank you Lucas. I know that ISO and CIS are different - guess what I should have asked is for their relative value as a certification. Guess O-TTPF should apply to all external components to be valid. Thanks again.

Comment: If you mean you want to be able to show third parties, like banks, that you have your security under control. Then indeed ISO27k1 and CIS makes sense. They are both industry wide recognized.

Comment: Yes, I wanted to confirm that. I am going ahead for ISO27001 and I am trying to get a buy-in for CIS too from my team. I want to establish a standard practice that will improve customer trust. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Payment processing software involving cards (debit, credit, etc.) falls under the purview of the Payment Card Industry Data Security Standards (PCI DSS) and more specifically the Payment Application Data Security Standards (PA-DSS) published by the [PCI Security Standards Council](https://www.pcisecuritystandards.org/). As such, there is a wealth of information on this site under the tag [pci-dss](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pci-dss). You may want to add this tag to the post to make sure people who are knowledgeable in this field see it.

Comment: Thank you Mike. That's useful info. As I am a newbie here, there is a limit on the tags I can add I guess. My up-voting of your answer too is pending till I cross a rep of 15.